# Google search results with javascript, API

Tags: javascript, search

I need to get results from google search engine programaticaly with JavaScript. Of course I can't do this with ajax because of CORS, but is there any other way?

I've seen custom search API which adds search box on website, but I just need data. Many Google docs are already deprecated, so is there any way to do this? (I know I could do this with PHP, but need to do this with javascript).

Ok I figured out that I can't run custom search GET because of localhost, as far as I know CX only work for domain that I add. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: i guess google allows `CORS`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: allows or does not allow? OP suggests CORS is an issue, therefore it would seem that google does not allow CORS

Answer (score 0):

Should be somthing like this `GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures`

You will need to set up an api key though

You can find more here:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Comment: I have created something like this:  $.get( "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MYKEY&cx=MYCX&q=lectures", function( data ) {
   $( ".result" ).html( data );
   alert( "Load was performed." );
 });   but it still doesn't work, I get error 400 in console

Comment: I have also tested their code with cars example from API docs, it doesn't work aswell - of course I've added my key + cx